# If $f(0) = g(0)$ and f is not a constant function, show that $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for any other value of $x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If $$f = 2\arctan(e^{x+C}),\quad g = 2\arctan(e^{({\sqrt\pi \operatorname{erf} (x)}/{2})+C)})$$

and $f(0) = g(0)$, and $f$ is not a constant function, how do I show that $f$ does not equal $g$ for any other value of $x$?

Comment: The word "any" can be misunderstood, since it sometimes means "all" (Any positive number has a positive square root) and sometimes means "some" (Does this equation have any solution?). I have met mathematicians who are non-native English speakers and are confused by the use of "any". Therefore I suggest changing "any" in the heading and the body of the question to "every" to make your meaning clearer.  And why say "if $f$ is not a constant function" when the $f$ you give is clearly never a constant function (no matter what $C$ is in $f(x)$).

Comment: Are the C's in the expressions the same?  If so $f(0)\ne g(0)$.

Comment: yes the c's are the same... they are equal?

Answer (score 0):

Tou are considering the two functions
$$f(x)=2 \tan ^{-1}\left(e^{x+c}\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad g(x)=2 \tan ^{-1}\left(e^{\sqrt{\pi }\, \text{erf}(x)+c}\right)$$
There are always three roots to the equation $f(x)=g(x)$ and one is trivial $x=0$.

What happens is that
$$f'(0)= \frac{2 e^c}{e^{2 c}+1} \qquad \text{and} \qquad g'(0)=\frac{4 e^c}{e^{2 c}+1}=2f'(0)$$ So, at for small values of $x$, $g(x)$ increases twice faster than $f(x)$.

But, the asymptotic value of $f(x)$ is a constant $\pi$ while it is systematically lower the $\pi$ for $g(x)$.

Comparing the arguments, in practice, we look for the zero's of function
$$h(x)=x-\sqrt{\pi }\, \text{erf}(x)$$ which does not make any trouble using Newton method, the solution being $x=\pm 1.74871$

If you do not want to use numerical methods, you could make some approximation. The function $h'(x)$ cancels at $x=\pm \sqrt{\log (2)}$. Making a second order Taylor expansion around this value $x_0=\sqrt{\log (2)}$ and solving the quadratic
$$x_1=x_0+\sqrt{-2\frac {h(x_0)}{h''(x_0)}}$$ that is to say
$$x_1=\sqrt{\log (2)}+\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{\log (2)}} \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\log (2)}\right)-1} \sim 1.61999$$

We could also make the infinte series
$$\frac {h(x)}x=-1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{  x^{2 n}}{(2 n+1)\, n!}$$ and, truncating it to order $O(x^{2(p+1)})$ use series reversion.

As a function of $p$, the numerical values of the *estimate* will be in the form
$$x_{(p)}=\frac {a_p} {b_p}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$$ Numerically, the $x_{p}$ generate the sequence
$$\{1.22474,1.50031,1.61890,1.67850,1.71030,1.72769,1.73729,1.74259,1.74549\}$$

If you use Newton mathod starting with $x_1$, the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{iterate} \\
 0 & 1.619987725 \\
 1 & 1.752776245 \\
 2 & 1.748711937 \\
 3 & 1.748708965
\end{array}
\right)$$

Just for the fun, the solution is close to $$\frac{3+\sqrt[3]{3}}{2+\cos (1)}\sim 1.748709026$$